# logging using winston not making new file

Tags: node.js, kafka-consumer-api, winston

i am  using winston to add logs in my nodejs project which is basically a kakfka based service which runs 24 x 7, below code only generate log on separate file(the file dated when the service restarted) but it only changes file when the i restart the server after the change date, is their anything which automatically changes the log file when the day changes.

```
const {createLogger, format, transports} = require("winston");
const {combine, timestamp, label, prettyPrint} = format;

const logger = createLogger({
    level: "info",
    format: format.combine(
        format.splat(),
        format.simple(),
        format.json(),
        timestamp(),
        prettyPrint()
    ),
    transports: [
        new transports.File({
            filename: `${appRoot}/Log/error/Log_${new Date().getUTCDate()}-${new Date().getMonth()}-${new Date().getFullYear()}.log`,
            level: "error",
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: true,
            stack: true,
        }),

        
        
    ],
    exitOnError: false,
});

module.exports = logger;
```